# Inserting text with diacritics with Doctrine ORM using SQL Server 2005/2008

Tags: sql-server, utf-8

I am having a problem inserting text with diacritics in the database, the diacritics get removed and normal characters show up instead `(a, t, s)`, the only one that gets inserted is `î`. The column type is `TEXT` - Doctrine and `NVARCHAR` in SQL Server, and the `charset:  UTF8` in the config file. Also I am using Symfony2.

How can I set up Doctrine so the diacritics get inserted properly?

I tried adding `options.1002: "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"` but I only get php warnings that say:

> Warning: PDO::__construct(): SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support this function: driver does not support setting attributes

Comment: Which collation are you using? Does it support the diacritics you wish to enter?

Comment: I used a wrong collation, post this as an answer so I can mark it as accepted ;) thanks

Comment: I tried editing the old answer, but it seems admin are faster at deleting than at undeleting ;). (Also some info isn't visible on mobile, like the fact that it was converted in the first place...) Added a new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please keep in mind, that the collation used does not only determine how similar characters are treated, but also which characters are allowed. Your problem may be as simple as using a wrong collation.

Comment: Collation doesn't effect the characters which are allowed for Unicode data types (nvarchar in this case).  For Unicode collation only effects sort order.

Comment: The problem seems to be, that not all romanian diacritics are (yet?) in Unicode. I suppose the romanian collation provides some kind of workaround.